# PHP check if there is a file selected for upload Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image

That is my way to check file image uploaded or not , send from view to controller php laravel

```
$dataImages=$request->images;
if($dataImages[0] == ""){
            print_r("file null");
        }else{
            print_r("file not null");

            $pathImage='product_images/1/image-1651261589260.jpg';
            if(File::exists($pathImage)){
                File::delete($pathImage);
            }
        }
```

Comment: read the documentation.  There is a method for this.  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-uploads

Answer (score 1):

`Laravel` has a helper function in the `request` object fo that case called `hasFile`

```
if($request->hasFile('images')){
   // true
} else {
  // false
}
```

for more info check the [`Retrieving Uploaded Files`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files)